# CouchDB views moving

Tags: couchdb

I know that it is possible to backup your data by simply copying them
to some storage (on Linux they are usually installed under
/var/lib/couchdb/*.couch). Also in that same directories are data
indexed by views. I also know that you can make a copy of views by
sending HTTP requests to another database. But what I don't know is, is it
possible to save your views by simply copying them to a storage like
with data? To make my question a little bit clearer: Can you make
a backup of views without another database instance? Also, I am using 
CouchDB 1.6 which has different file structure than versions greater
than 2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me post an answer, this is only solution that i could think of...Of course it can be improved or changed but it works for me.
Script needs to be called from terminal (unless you edit it in some IDE) with

> sys.argv[1] like **python3 viewBackup.py 1** or **python3 viewBackup.py 2**

(1 is to make backup file, 2 is to upload that backup).Since this script is so simple there's no need for checking if backup file already exists (if there is backup made)

```
import requests
import json
import sys

# these are credentials of DB which views we want to backup
from_db = 'http://localhost:5984/'
from_user = 'root'
from_pswd = '1234'
from_auths = (from_user, from_pswd)

#`and these are credentials of DB where we want to upload our backuped views`
to_db = 'http://localhost:5984/'
to_user = 'root'
to_pswd = '1234'
to_auths = (from_user, from_pswd)

tf = 'bucket2views.json'




def getViews(source, credS):
    global tf
    data = _getDBList(source, credS)
    temp = []

    f = open(tf, 'w')
    for d in data:
        designs = requests.get(source + d + '/_all_docs?startkey="_design/"&endkey="_desing0"&include_docs=true',auth=credS).json()

        designs = designs['rows']


        for z in designs:
            z = z['doc']['_id'].split('/')
            z = z[1]
            try:

                print("getting views, it might take some time, please be patient")
                views = requests.get(source + d + '/_design/' + z, auth=credS).json()['views']
                print(" views gathered, start processing them")
                views2 = {'views': views}
                payload = json.dumps(views2)
                temp.append((d, z, payload))

            except Exception as e:
                pass


    f.write(json.dumps(temp))
    f.close()
    print(' views has been saved')

def _getDBList(server, auth):
    response = requests.get(server + '_all_dbs', auth=auth).json()
    return response

def uploadViews(srv, cred):
    f = open(tf, 'r')
    txt = f.read()
    f.close()

    jt = json.loads(txt)

    for item in jt:
        d = item[0]
        z = item[1]
        full_name = item[2]
        resp = requests.put(srv+ d +'/_design/'+ z, data=json.dumps(payload), auth=cred).json()
        print (json.dumps(resp))

def main():
    ans = sys.argv[1]
    # ans = 2
    if ans in [1, '1', 'getViews']:
        getViews(from_db, from_auths)

    elif ans in [2, '2', "uploadViews"]:
        uploadViews(to_db, to_auths)

    else:
        print('Possible inputs: 1, getViews, 2, uploadViews')

main()
```